# HL7 ORU sending edits

Tags: edit, hl7

I use HL7 ORU message to send clinical notes. At present, I just send notes as they are created and saved. But now I need to support edit and delete of the notes and convey the same to the receiving system.

How can I achieve edit / delete with this? I use ORU^R01 structure and use OBR and multiple OBX segments for my information. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to confirm with the receiving system how they want edits and deletes conveyed to them. But it is common to use the result status code in `OBR-25` and/or the observation result status code in `OBX-11`.

For example, if the clinical note is edited (aka. corrected or modified) send a `C` in `OBR-25`. If the clinical note is deleted send a `X` in `OBR-25`. Ultimately you will need to coordinate with the receiving system.

FWIW, I commonly see these values in `OBR-25`:

- `P` = preliminary
- `F` = final
- `C` = corrected / modified
- `X` = cancelled / deleted / in-error

Comment: Thanks for response. Would I send original note's unique control ID when it gets edited or deleted? i.e. Original message control ID is XXX. When edit happens, should that message's control ID be XXX?

Comment: The message control id in MSH-10? No. That should be unique and should not need to match the previous results message control id. You should have a unique order number (OBR-2 and/or OBR-3) that would be the same and let the system know "I'm updating the result for this order". But you should get this information in the form of specifications from the system you are sending to. That should tell you what they expect to see.